# Interpreting sign. interaction effect in multiple regression with two continous predictors

Tags: regression, interpretation

I have a data output from SPSS, where DV is work performance, and two continuous predictors. One predictor is IQ and one predictor is work experience (years). I have centered the predictors AND created and interaction term.

But, I cannot find any videos or information about how to interpret the significant effect. Anyone who understands how I should interpret this? For instance if IQ is the moderator.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can hardly trust those numerical results per se when the VIF is near 300.  The collinearity makes it near-impossible to tease out the relative contributions of each of the 3 predictors.  You need to visualize the relationships.  Try either

- a bubble plot (a scatterplot in which X-axis is C_IQ, y-axis is C_Erfaring, and the DV is graphed as a bubble whose size depends on the DV's value), or
- a 3D scatterplot.

With either approach, you would not plot the interaction effect per se, but you would be able to infer it.  As the product (the joint effect) of the two IV's becomes either very low or very high, what happens to the DV?

Edit:  While I see good information in @Sointu 's post, I disagree that it's necessary or always desirable to sacrifice fine-grained information by categorizing one of your continuous predictors.  That may be a fine starting point to aid in interpretation, but often you'll want the more precise findings obtainable through methods such as those I described.

Another approach is a 2-D scatterplot where y = the DV, plain and simple, and x = the product of the two main predictors.  This *will* literally graph your interaction, though it won't show its effect over and above the main effects the way coefficients will.

Comment: Hey, thank you! This is new information/new approach to me!

Comment: Glad it's a help!  Cheers ~

Answer (score 0):

EDIT. whoops, I didn't notice the huge VIFs - indeed, you have very high collinearity and the results may not be reliable. My response works when you have this kind of interaction without such collinearity or other problems.

First, it's good to visualize the interaction.

When you have a continuous by continuous interaction, you can choose one of the predictors to serve as "pseudo-categorical" (EDIT however, see Rolando's answer for a more fine-grained ways of visualizing an interaction) for this purpose and create a variable that represents for instance low, average and high values on this variable. IQ might serve well in this role as it has such a well established scale and norms.

So, you can create a three-level variable indicating whether your participants have IQ of lower than mean - 1sd, between -1sd and + 1 sd, and higher than mean + 1 sd. Then, plot the work experience - job performance slope for each of these groups into the same image (it may make more sense to use work experience as the "categorized" variable, you need to decide on the basis of your data and subject knowledge).

The significant interaction effect and the visualization may be enough for reporting the results. However, many people want to test whether the simple slopes (i.e. work experience -> job performance at different levels of IQ) differ from each other, or from some pre-defined value (e.g. zero).

The way I know how to do this is via t-test. This is easy to do in R, but I'm not sure how to do it in SPSS.

However, you can do it manually by 1) computing the simple slope estimates (i.e. the regression coefficients for the work experience -> job performance relation for the three different levels of IQ); 2) subtracting the coefficients from one another (you do this separately for each pair, low vs. average, average vs. high, low vs. high) and 3) dividing the difference with pooled standard error. This gives you the t-statistic for the difference between two slope coefficients. Degrees of freedom for each pairwise test would be n-2.

[See here](https://www.glmj.org/archives/articles/Robinson_v39n1.pdf) for a practical guide.